# Como obtener el valor del segundo spinner. Quitando saltos de línea extras

Tags: java, android, api

Tengo dos `spinner`, el primero muestra las bodegas y el segundo se rellena con productos dependiendo de la bodega seleccionada, mi problema se genera cuando quiero obtener el valor del segundo `spinner`, por que cuando selecciono una bodega y me rellena me toma siempre el primer valor del segundo `spinner`, incluso si selecciono otro.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    cargaSpinnerProductos(spinnerB.getSelectedItemPosition());
    nombre = spinnerP.getSelectedItem().toString();

    System.out.println(nombre);

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

public void cargaSpinnerProductos(int prod){

    adaptador0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 this, R.array.gdos_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                 adaptador0.setDropDownViewResource(
                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adaptador1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 this, R.array.bseleccion_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                 adaptador1.setDropDownViewResource(
                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adaptador2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 this, R.array.Spopreprocesos_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                 adaptador2.setDropDownViewResource(
                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adaptador3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 this, R.array.gtres_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                 adaptador3.setDropDownViewResource(
                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adaptador4 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 this, R.array.gcuatro_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                 adaptador4.setDropDownViewResource(
                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adaptador5 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 this, R.array.spgcuatrovc_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                 adaptador5.setDropDownViewResource(
                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adaptador6 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 this, R.array.pterrack_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                 adaptador6.setDropDownViewResource(
                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adaptador7 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 this, R.array.spgcuatromvc_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                 adaptador7.setDropDownViewResource(
                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adaptador8 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 this, R.array.canigtresgcuatro_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                 adaptador8.setDropDownViewResource(
                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adaptador9 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 this, R.array.canigdos_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                 adaptador9.setDropDownViewResource(
                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    switch (prod) {
        case 0:
            spinnerP.setAdapter(adaptador0);
            break;
        case 1:
            spinnerP.setAdapter(adaptador1);
            break;
        case 2:
            spinnerP.setAdapter(adaptador2);
            break;
        case 3:
            spinnerP.setAdapter(adaptador3);
            break;
        case 4:
            spinnerP.setAdapter(adaptador4);
            break;
        case 5:
            spinnerP.setAdapter(adaptador5);
            break;
        case 6:
            spinnerP.setAdapter(adaptador6);
            break;
        case 7:
            spinnerP.setAdapter(adaptador7);
            break;
        case 8:
            spinnerP.setAdapter(adaptador8);
            break;
        case 9:
            spinnerP.setAdapter(adaptador9);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Solo como consejo ahorrate de inicializar todos los adaptadores antes de que sepas cual, mejor en el case inicializa el adaptador.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu codigo tu seleccionas el valor del primer `spinner` que es bodegas. Obtienes la posición de ese `spinner` seleccionada y seteas al segundo `spinner` los valores correspondientes a la bodega.

Como te dije en el comentario ahorrate inicializar el adapter antes de saber que bodega se selecciono.

```
switch (prod) {
     case 0:
        adaptador0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
             this, R.array.gdos_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
             adaptador0.setDropDownViewResource(
             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerP.setAdapter(adaptador0);
        break;
}
```

El problema es que tu "seleccionas" el valor del primer `spinner` cargas el segundo `spinner` e inmediatamente traes el primer valor.

Lo que debes hacer es tambien capturar el evento `setOnItemSelectedListener` del segundo `spinner`

Spinner 1

Aqui lo que haces es que cuando cambie el primero, solo llamas a la funcion que carga la data a tu segundo spinner.

```
spinnerB.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        cargaSpinnerProductos(spinnerB.getSelectedItemPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

    }

});
```

Spinner 2

Cuando cambie, se llama al evento `setOnItemSelectedListener` y se obtiene el elemento seleccionado.

```
spinnerP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        nombre = spinnerP.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println("Nombre : "+nombre);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

    }

});
```

Comment: aun si capturo el evento me sigue seleccionando el primer valor del segundo spinner =(

Comment: Puedes hacer un `System.out.println(position)` cada vez que cambias el valor del segundo spinner?

Comment: no me imprime la posicion =/

Comment: Es extraño que no lo imprima, tienes separadas las capturas de los eventos para ambos spinner?

Comment: @LeslieKarenFigueroaMeneses  deberia estar asi como actualice mi respuesta